# Database Restore info not logged to msdb..restorehistory

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore, msdb

I have 4 databases on a secondary server two of which are using Sql Server log shipping and two of which are using a "manual log shipping" config (there are just 2 primary databases).

Both implementations on the secondary server were initialized using Backups from the two primary databases.

The issue I currently have is only one of the databases which is being replicated on the secondary server is writing information to msdb..restorehistory.

To be clear it is working for both implementations of one database but neither implementation of the other.

I can't see a setting somewhere that would mean this would not happen and it's definitely not getting cleared as I'm checking instantly after a restore operation.

Anybody any thoughts on why a restore operation wouldn't be getting written to msdb..restorehistory?

Comment: RestoreHistory in msdb can be deleted by anyone with the required privileges or the command sp_delete_backuphistory. Could this be your problem? Do you have some purging jobs?

Comment: 99.99% certain that's not happening. It's certainly not another user and there are no jobs set up. Thanks

Comment: Have you did someting like detach/attach with database wothout history?